# Verify the order in which a method have been called with different arguments

Tags: java, mockito

I would like to verify that my method is invoked with different arguments in a fixed order.
I've tried this:

```
org.mockito.Mockito.verify(mock).myMethod(arg1);
org.mockito.Mockito.verify(mock).myMethod(arg2);
//was myMethod called with arg1 before it was called with arg2?
```

but that does not take order into account. 
Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mockito provide [InOrder](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InOrder.html) to verify call in orders

take a look this document : [Verification in order](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#in_order_verification)

example :

```
MyClass mock = mock(MyClass.class);
InOrder order = inOrder(mock);

order.verify(mock).myMethod("first");
order.verify(mock).myMethod("second");
```

last two line will verify mock object been called in that order and arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html). Here is a snippet from Mockito Javadoc:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Person> peopleCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
   verify(mock, times(2)).doSomething(peopleCaptor.capture());

   List<Person> capturedPeople = peopleCaptor.getAllValues();
   assertEquals("John", capturedPeople.get(0).getName());
   assertEquals("Jane", capturedPeople.get(1).getName());
```